# dictionary code in file to dictionary in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a .txt file which is saved like this:
{('A', 0): -1, ('A', 1): -1, ('A', 2): 0, ('B', 0): -1, ('B', 1): 0, ('B', 2): 0, ('C', 0): 0, ('C', 1): 0, ('C', 2): 0}
which should become a dict if you code it like this `dict = {('A', 0): -1, ('A', 1): -1, ('A', 2): 0, ('B', 0): -1, ('B', 1): 0, ('B', 2): 0, ('C', 0): 0, ('C', 1): 0, ('C', 2): 0}`
but if import the text from the file to a string so that the string is the raw text (like this `txtfromfile = "{('A', 0): -1, ('A', 1): -1, ('A', 2): 0, ('B', 0): -1, ('B', 1): 0, ('B', 2): 0, ('C', 0): 0, ('C', 1): 0, ('C', 2): 0}"` and I do this
`dict = txtfromfile` it makes the dict a string. Is there a way to make it a dict instead of a string?

Comment: import json then use json.loads(string)

Comment: @JeremySavage That would only work if the dictionary keys were strings. Here, though, the keys are tuples.

Comment: How was the text file created in the first place? Was it intended to be a JSON, but didn't because of keys being tuples?

Comment: @jjramsey Ahh didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `literal_eval` function from the `ast` built-in module:

```py
import ast

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as fp:
    mydict = ast.literal_eval(fp.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads(text)` will do the trick.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: That won't work with dictionaries that have tuples as keys, which is what the opening post has.

Comment: Oh shoot, good point.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Learned from the comment that `eval` should not be used for this. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/7947994). The proper solution is the answer suggesting `ast.literal_eval()`.

You <s>can</s> **should not** use the following to evaluate the text:

```
txtfromfile = "{('A', 0): -1, ('A', 1): -1, ('A', 2): 0, ('B', 0): -1, ('B', 1): 0, ('B', 2): 0, ('C', 0): 0, ('C', 1): 0, ('C', 2): 0}"

my_dict = eval(txtfromfile)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{('A', 0): -1, ('A', 1): -1, ('A', 2): 0, ('B', 0): -1, ('B', 1): 0, ('B', 2): 0, ('C', 0): 0, ('C', 1): 0, ('C', 2): 0}
```

Comment: please, don't suggest eval or exec for a task like this.